# Can a function call an other function in the same namespace and in same partial class but in a different file

Tags: c#, wpf, class, partial, partial-classes

I have a partial class defined in two different `.cs` (`Part1.cs`, `Part2.cs`) and I'm not able to call a function in `part1.cs` from `part2.cs`. Is it possible to do it ? 
Both `.cs` are in the same folder and can use other class in the folder (`class1.cs`,`class2.cs`,...)

This is what I'm trying to do:

### Part1.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public void Two()
        { }

        public void Three()
        { }
    }
}
```

### Part2

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public void One()
        {
           Two();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you have?

Comment: `i'm not able to call a function in part1.cs from part2.cs` Why do you think so?

Comment: The Name 'Two' does not exist in the current context !
 The function is not recognize at all .

Comment: Are you sure part1.cs is set to compile?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in Part2.  I assume this is just a typo in your simplified version and not something wrong with your actual code.

Comment: Maybe they are not supossed to ? But normally functions from the same class can use each others, and functions from different classes can call each other too!? Soe i really dont see why this is not working? Do u have a clue for me Hamlet Hakobyan

Comment: Yes, you can do it. In fact, doing this exact thing is a big reason partial classes exist: you can have one side created using code generation, and the other side hand-written. They can then work together without having to modify any generated code. What people are saying is that there's some other problem here: you should include the *exact* error(s) that you're getting in the post.

Comment: Both part are compiling without any error, the problem happend when i try to use the function.  The problem is not the closing brace, typing mistake

Comment: Are you compiling from within Visual Studio?  Or are you using the command-line C# compiler?  If the latter, are you compiling both files in the same step?

Comment: I just try to recreate all the files from scratch and now it's working fine ? I really don't understand ! I think the problem was in my function one() definition 0_0 thx 31eee and adv12 You help me out :)